# Marshaling structure to string

Tags: c#

I have a struct for concat string datas.

```
 public struct MyClass1
    {

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 5)]
        public string Name;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 5)]
        public string SurName;
    }
```

I set the value struct fields.

```
MyStruct mystr = new MyStruct();

mystr.Name = 'John';
mystr.SurName = 'Smith';
```

I want to concat this string by using Marshaling and get the value as

> "John Smith"

. Is it possible using marshaling ?

Comment: If you want to concatenate strings, use the `+` operator. Marshalling is unrelated.

Comment: Someone always manages to surprise me

Comment: `Smith\0` is already too long for a `char[5]`.

Comment: for example using Marshal.StructureToPtr(..) i want get the result.

Comment: Why do you want to use Marshaling? You do not make that clear.

Comment: Because i using Marshaling to setting string to structer. I want to reverse assigning.

Comment: Marshaling is for interaction with unmanaged code. Any of that involved?

Comment: Marshaling is very easy way to setting values a struct. It set the value giving sizeconst. Dont you suggest use marshaling?

Comment: Easier than your second code snippet where you just call the constructor and initialize each field directly?

Comment: my purpose is DeSerialize structure and concat values.

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection instead of marshalling.

```
 var myClass = new MyClass1 { Name = "John", SurName = "Smith" };
 Console.WriteLine(MyMarshal(myClass));

static string MyMarshal(object item)
{
  var values = new List<object>();
  foreach (var field in item.GetType().GetFields())
  {
    values.Add(field.GetValue(item));
  }
  return string.Join(" ", values.ToArray());
}

public struct MyClass1 
{  
    public string Name; 

    public string SurName; 
}
```